# Rails returning weird JSON with Objective -c's NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm working on an API using Rails & Objective -c.

Objective -c side:

```
NSLog(@"NSArray: %@", allPosts);
```

I suppose it's something going on in my rails side. I was expecting to get back something like this:

```
{
id: 1,
galleries: [
{
id: 1,
name: "my gallery",
user_id: 1,
post_id: 1
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting this -> "`<Post: 0x102439>`"?

---

NSLog

```
MyBlog[17577:303] [OUT] ===> GET to http://localhost:3000/posts 
MyBlog[17577:303] NSArray: (
    "<Post: 0x102130060>"
)
```

Comment: what's the current output and what is the output of the NSLog statement? pretty unclear to me what's really going on here.

Comment: @moritz sorry, I forgot to add that in but I just edited it in there above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your NSLog-Statement it seems everything is working ok. You might want to set a breakpoint and inspect the allPosts array, but the log output basically indicates that there is an object of the class Post, the latter part is just the memory address.